# Can I Share Daedalus Public Key?

Tags: daedalus, security, public-key

I am trying to add my accounts to a coin baalance tracker, but am having a hard time with Daedalus.

The only option that seems to make any sense is sharing the public key with the tracker apps. Is this safe?

Answer (score 1):

for the sake of potential loss of your balance i wold say dont untill your absolutely sure but you would assume yes seeing as its called a public key meaning its publicly visible

Answer (score 1):

Cryptography is the science of secret writing with the intention of keeping the data secret. Cryptography is classified into symmetric cryptography, asymmetric cryptography and hashing.

Private Key:
In Private key, the same key (secret key) is used for encryption and decryption. In this key is symmetric because the only key is copy or share by another party to decrypt the cipher text. It is faster than the public key cryptography.

Public Key:
In Public key, two keys are used one key is used for encryption and another key is used for decryption. One key (public key) is used for encrypt the plain text to convert it into cipher text and another key (private key) is used by receiver to decrypt the cipher text to read the message.